# Why is Force.com User is not checked by default?

Tags: flow, setup

Any one knows why the Force.com Flow user is not checked by default?

It's not licenses based so I don't see the reason.

[image]

It's not even in the standard user fields for the User Object

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is considered a feature license, defined by Salesforce [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_understanding_feature_licenses.htm&language=en_US):  Feature Licenses

> **Overview**
>
> A feature license entitles a user to access an additional feature that
>   is not included with his or her user license, such as Marketing or
>   Work.com. Users can be assigned any number of feature licenses.

---

> Edition requirements vary for each feature licenses.

Feature license availability is [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_feature_licenses_available.htm&language=en_US).

Answer (score 2):

Probably because it used to be license based. Do you remember Flow Interviews?

Comment: don't remember Flow Interviews.

Comment: They were the predecessors to what are now called Visual Flows and required an additional license.