# Why not enable Flow User?

Tags: flow, licenses, feature-activation

I understand [why Salesforce does not default users to Flow users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/79222/7195).  However, is there a reason to not check off the **Force.com Flow User** checkbox when adding a new user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, if a feature license requires you to pay for the license, then the answer comes down to money. Did you buy enough licenses for *every* user in your org to use that feature.

If the answer is **yes** then rock on with your bad self. Turn that on for everyone.

If the answer is **no** then of course, you'll have to be selective.

As to this particular feature license, I think we charged for it initially...a long time ago. But I don't recall if we charge for this anymore in production orgs.

If a feature license is a legacy license and it is now free for everyone, then go back to  the **yes** part above.

Finally...if there are users you just don't want using the flows at all...then why tick the box?